# How to get this numerical solution of a integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

Previously, I ask an NDSolve questions(https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84885/how-to-solve-the-differential-equation-with-duhamels-integral), but now a more sophisticated one:

```
NDSolve[{0.01-10 (0.01 t-x[t]) + (3 Integrate[(1+10 (0.01 (t-τ)-x[t-τ])) x'[t-τ]/Sqrt[τ], {τ, 0, t}])/10^7 == 10 x''[t], 
x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Why not help *Mathematica* out a bit and see if you can turn your integro-differential equation into an ODE?

Comment: @Guess who it is    Thanks for your good advise. Maybe I should ask this question in Mathematics.

Comment: @ScottWang That is not what guesswho was hinting at. The suggestion is to take the derivative of your main equation to get rid of the integral and make it a real ordinary differential equation.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries   I have asked this in Math. This question will be closed. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is much more difficult than your original problem and beyond my reach now. BTW, do you create this equation based on some reference or just in a… casual way?